# How can I resolve this issue on SonarCloud?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarcloud

Using `SonarCloud` I got this ***bug***:

`Use try-with-resources or close this "ResultSet" in a "finally" clause`

This is the following code:

```
public long executeUpdate() throws SQLException {
    if (query != null) {
        try {
            statement.execute();
            if (returnGeneratedKeys) {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    return resultSet.getLong(1);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this:

```
public long executeUpdate() throws SQLException {
    if (query != null) {
        try {
            statement.execute();
            if (returnGeneratedKeys) {
                try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                        return resultSet.getLong(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The following structure:

```
try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        return resultSet.getLong(1);
    }
}
```

is equal to:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys()
try {
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        return resultSet.getLong(1);
    }
} finally {
    if (resultSet != null) {
        resultSet.close()
    }
}
```